# Copy Mat by reference

Tags: java, kotlin, opencv

I am using OpenCV for Java in one of my projects. I have some image data in memory in a `Mat` and would like to create a second reference pointing to the same native memory (i.e. copy the `Mat` by reference). The background is that I am using the `Mat` at multiple places and want all instances to point to the same data while allowing all usages to `release()` their references once they are done using them to avoid memory leaks.

Currently, I am doing this as follows:

```kotlin
fun Mat.copyByReference(): Mat = this.submat(0, rows(), 0, cols())
```

This works fine, but not for subclasses of `Mat` (like e.g. `MatOfKeyPoint`) because `submat()` always returns a `Mat`. My question is therefore whether there's a suitable way to achieve this for all subclasses of `Mat`.

Comment: If you're just referencing all the same pixels of the whole Mat, why make a new Mat instance at all instead of just passing the same Mat instance to the other class?

Comment: Because if the `Mat` is released in one place, the other code also no longer has access to the data. Therefore, if I pass the same instance of `Mat` along, I need to keep track of where it is used to not release it while it is still in use somewhere while not keeping it in memory longer than it needs to be to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. That's a shame that it doesn't keep track of the references it's been handing out, but I guess it's not a Java-first library so it's not designed for that.

Comment: Well, yes, it is, but in native code. As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127126/what-happens-to-submats-if-the-original-mat-is-released), OpenCV indeed does reference counting, but because it has no idea about Java's GC, the user has to tell it when it is safe to release a reference. The actual memory will only be released though when all references are gone.

Comment: So it's not decrementing its native reference counting when `finalize` is called in a class instance? I would have expected them to have `finalize()` call `release()` in case the user misses calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the source code of `Mat.java` it seems that there's one constructor of `Mat` that does exactly what I want:

```java
public Mat(Mat m, Rect roi) {
    this.nativeObj = n_Mat(m.nativeObj, roi.y, roi.y + roi.height, roi.x, roi.x + roi.width);
}
```

This constructor also exists for all subclasses, except that those do not take a roi. I therefore modified my function as follows:

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T : Mat> T.copyByReference(): T = when (this) {
    is MatOfByte -> MatOfByte(this)
    is MatOfDMatch -> MatOfDMatch(this)
    is MatOfDouble -> MatOfDouble(this)
    is MatOfFloat -> MatOfFloat(this)
    is MatOfFloat4 -> MatOfFloat4(this)
    is MatOfFloat6 -> MatOfFloat6(this)
    is MatOfInt -> MatOfInt(this)
    is MatOfInt4 -> MatOfInt4(this)
    is MatOfKeyPoint -> MatOfKeyPoint(this)
    is MatOfPoint -> MatOfPoint(this)
    is MatOfPoint2f -> MatOfPoint2f(this)
    is MatOfPoint3 -> MatOfPoint3(this)
    is MatOfPoint3f -> MatOfPoint3f(this)
    is MatOfRect -> MatOfRect(this)
    is MatOfRect2d -> MatOfRect2d(this)
    is MatOfRotatedRect -> MatOfRotatedRect(this)
    else -> Mat(this, Rect(0, 0, cols(), rows()))
} as T
```